# Excel: replacing part of value in Column B with value of Column A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vba

I have a spreadsheet where Column A is filled with values like:

```
Admin Chair
Aida Chair
Albany Arm Chair
Albany Chair
Alfred Function Chair
```

And in each corresponding Column B cell is this exact value:

```
Looking to include an XXXX in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today.
```

I am looking to create a formula that will allow me to replace every instance of "XXXX" with the corresponding Column A value. So for example, the formula would make B1 and B2 read instead:

```
Looking to include an Admin Chair in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today.
Looking to include an Aida Chair in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today.
```

And so on. Anyone done something similar before?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to have a formula in column C (rather than replacing what is in column B) you could use a formula in C1 of

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"XXXX",A1)
```

The above, when copied down, would modify whatever value was in column B of any row with whatever was in column A of the same row.

This could be useful if you want different rows to have different text for column A to be included within (e.g. you might have some of your rows saying `"Looking to include ..."` and some other rows saying something like `"You recently purchased a table from us.  Are you interested in purchasing a XXXX to go with it?"`)

However, if the value in column B is *always* the same for every row, you could use an absolute reference to the cell in B1, and not have to have that same value in every other row:

```
=SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"XXXX",A1)
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want an extra column to be used, and really want to replace what is in column B, and it is currently always the string `"Looking to include an XXXX in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today."`, then you could use a formula in B1 of

```
=SUBSTITUTE("Looking to include an XXXX in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today.","XXXX",A1)
```

or even the slightly simpler

```
="Looking to include an "&A1&" in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today."
```

Comment: Bah! Beat me by a second.

Comment: Also, if that string is in, say `B1`, OP could do this in `C1` and drag down: `=SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"XXXX",$A1)`.  All does the same thing though.

Comment: @BruceWayne Good point Bat... oops, Bruce - I'll add a note to that effect.

Comment: @BruceWayne LOL - what started of as a two line answer has become quite long now!

Comment: This isn't even it's final form! You should add a VBA solution, there's also Find/Replace, and of course the obvious (which is why I assume it's not even mentioned), `=LEFT($B$1,SEARCH(REPT("X",4),$B$1)-1)&$A1&MID($B$1,SEARCH(REPT("x",(2*2)),$B$1,1)+LEN("xxxx"),LEN($B$1)-SEARCH("xxxx",$B$1))`

Comment: @BruceWayne I had to leave you at least **one** formula you could post yourself - I dare you to do so!! But make sure you add a complete explanation for each component of that formula :D  (BTW - I think you have a mistake in that formula - isn't the last `"xxxx"` meant to be `LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(REPT("Z",10),"Z","X"),5-FACT(0))`? ;) )

Comment: D'oh! You're right, dumb typo on my part! And I should probably have used `Indirect()` somewhere in there too, and explicitly give the sheet the cells are on, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this makes more or less sense than SUBSTITUTE or simple string concatenation but here is an alternative with REPLACE.

List of originals in column A; list of replacements in column B. In C1,

```
=replace(a1, find("XXXX", a1), 4, b1)
```

> <sub>Looking to include an Admin Chair in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today.
>
>   Looking to include an Aida Chair in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today.
>
>   Looking to include an Albany Arm Chair in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today.
>   Looking to include an Albany Chair in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today.
>
>   Looking to include an Alfred Function Chair in your cafe or restaurant fit-out? Get an easy and instant quote from us today.</sub>